# Passing derived class by reference to function taking base class as parameter

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Consider the following code:

```c++
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() { }

    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "In A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { }
    virtual ~B() { }

    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "In B" << std::endl;
    }
};

void doSomething(A* a) {
    a->print();
}

void doSomething(const A a) {
    a.print();
}

int main()
{
    A* a = new B();
    doSomething(a);
    doSomething(B());
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this output:

```
In B
In A
```

But when you change `doSomething` to `doSomething(const A& a)` it outputs:

```
In B
In B
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is known as *slicing*.

When passing `A` by value, a local copy is made, by copying just the `A` part of the caller's object. Since this has both a static and dynamic type of `A`, that's the override of `print` that's chosen.

Passing by reference, the function gets a reference to the caller's object with dynamic type `B`, so that override is chosen.

Using abstract base classes can prevent confusing behaviour like this - they can't be directly instantiated, and so can't be passed by value.